# Angular UI bootstrap timepicker uses new Date() as a model, how do elegantly wrap it to display UTC time to the user?

Tags: angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, utc, bootstrap-datetimepicker

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/timepicker

Angular UI bootstrap timepicker uses "new Date()" as a model, how do elegantly wrap it to display UTC time to the user?  (new Date() uses local timezone)

I'm using momentjs to manage my datetimes but when i bind it to this directive it converts it to my local timezone.

I was trying to avoid adding the timezone offset hours on the way in, and subtracting them on the way out?   I was hoping for something more elegant or  Angular-y.

Or is there a better alternative directive?

Comment: Here is a handy plunkr for the problem...   http://plnkr.co/edit/2JByf4?p=preview

Comment: AngularStrap seems to be a bootstrap-ui alternative, but i haven't figured around the same problem yet. http://plnkr.co/edit/GpK3dIsO3GyVV74uc3ET?p=preview

Comment: It looks like they're working to patch angularstraps timepicker to take a timezone.  https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/pull/1449

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating the date on your model using `Date.UTC`:

```
// controller
$scope.utcDate = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, minute, second));
```

```
<!-- view -->
<timepicker ng-model="utcDate"></timepicker>
```

Untested, so it probably won't work.

Alternatively, super long shot, you could try binding to the output of [`moment.utc()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) and hoping for the best :-).

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Sadly no avail.   It still renders that correct time in local timezone.  I appreciate it, though.